# Javascript not creating two <divs> via a for loop

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function createDiv(x) {
  var dIv, t;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    dIv = document.createElement("DIV");
    t = document.createTextNode(i);
    dIv.appendChild(t);
    dIv.id = i;
    dIv.style.color = "blue";
    dIv.style.width = "100%";
    dIv.style.height = "100%";
    document.getElementById("SAREE").appendChild(dIv);
  }
}
```

The above code is to create multiple  depends the value passed (x). But
only one  with id = 0 is created.

Comment: The code in that function never references `x`.

Comment: is `3` meant as a placeholder for `x` ? have you debugged the function and checked what's happening ?

Comment: I believe it is I++ instead of ++I?

Comment: @RandomChannel in this case either will work

Comment: How are you invoking this function?

Comment: Sir, x is meant for no of <divs> in the above code I tried for 3 <divs> any how only one <div> is created even the control pass through the entire loop. This is my problem. My intention is to create variable <divs> to  display data from a XML file. The no of <divs> varry

Answer (score 0):

It's working, but the div take 100% of the body, just scroll down to see the others....

Try to replace height: 100% by height : 10% wand you will see all...

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference `x` in the for loop count. That will give you the correct amount of divs.

```js
function createDiv(x) {
  var dIv, t;
  for (i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
    dIv = document.createElement("DIV");
    t = document.createTextNode(i);
    dIv.appendChild(t);
    dIv.id = i;
    dIv.style.color = "blue";
    dIv.style.width = "100%";
    dIv.style.height = "100%";
    document.getElementById("SAREE").appendChild(dIv);
  }
}
createDiv(2)
createDiv(5)
```

```html
<div id="SAREE"></div>
```